# Why does my page go up after every post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    var main = function(){
  $('.btn').click(function() {
     var post = $('.status-box').val();
     $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
     $('.status-box').val('');
     $('.counter').text('140');
     $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
  });
  $('.status-box').keyup(function(){
    var postLength = $(this).val().length;
    var charactersLeft = 140 - postLength;
    $('.counter').text(charactersLeft);
    if (charactersLeft < 0){
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
      }
      else if (charactersLeft == 140){
        $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
      }
      else {
        $('.btn').removeClass('disabled');
      }
  });
   $('.btn').addClass('disabled');
};

$(document).ready(main);
```

My page keeps going to the top every time I make a post any ideas of why this would be happening? I have a div with an option to make a 140 character post that gets put into a list and display on the page. Every time I make one of these posts the webpage goes up to the top and to see the post you must scroll all the way back down.

Comment: could you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: i tried to use it fiddle. I havent really ever used it before but here it is.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kv36jt98/

Comment: fiddle seems to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/kv36jt98/1/

Comment: O lol i did @Asaph fix below and it worked!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, the default form submission or link following behavior is executing in addition to your custom event logic. It's probably navigating to `#` or some other anchor near the top of your page. To prevent that from happening change

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
    ...
```

to

```
$('.btn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Comment: If form submits, the page will reload, right? Rather `.btn` is just an anchor tag - exactly as you presume in your answer.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Depends on what the target is. If the form posts to `"#"`, then it just navigates to the top of the page. My guess is that's what's going on.

Comment: Right, but why do you think there is a form ))

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if the page reloads or not because if I push the reload button on the web browser the post history is cleared and nothing is displayed. However when I click post the webpage jumps to the top and if you scroll down to the posts you can see the posts. I guess a fix would be to put the post button and posts on top of the webpage but i am curious to why this behavior occurs.

Comment: also thank you for the responses I am fairly new at web coding so its nice to get some help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @NikolayErmakov Even if it's an `<a>` tag and not a form, the default behavior is to navigate to the `href` target, and if the `<a>` tag has `href="#"` then the default behavior is still to navigate to the top of the page and the answer still applies. I'll reword the answer to allow for this to be an `<a>` or `<form>`, but the gist is the same.

Comment: @Asaph - I'm not arguing the answer, it is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ahhh i see. Thank you that makes sense!

Comment: @sizz - don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer ))

Comment: Thank you! I just did that but apparently my votes aren't counted because im not high enough rep yet!